# Efficient message factory and handler in C++

Tags: performance, c++11, handler, message

Our company is rewriting most of the legacy C code in C++11. (Which also means I am a C programmer learning C++). I need advice on message handlers.

We have distributed system - Server process sends a packed message over TCP to client process.

In C code this was being done:
    - parse message based on type and subtype, which are always the first 2 fields

```
- call a handler as handler[type](Message *msg)

- handler creates temporary struct say, tmp_struct to hold the parsed values and .. 

- calls subhandler[type][subtype](tmp_struct)
```

There is only one handler per type/subtype.

Moving to C++11 and mutli-threaded environment. The basic idea I had was to -

1)  Register a processor object for each type/subtype combination. This is
   actually a vector of vectors - 
   vector< vector >

```
class MsgProcessor {

    // Factory function
    virtual Message *create();
    virtual Handler(Message *msg)
}
```

This will be inherited by different message processors

```
class AMsgProcessor : public MsgProcessor {

      Message *create() override();
      handler(Message *msg);
}
```

2) Get the processor using a lookup into the vector of vectors.
   Get the message using the overloaded create() factory function.
   So that we can keep the actual message and the parsed values inside the  message.

3) Now a bit of hack, This message should be send to other threads for the heavy processing. To avoid having to lookup in the vector again, added a pointer to proc inside the message.

```
class Message {
    const MsgProcessor *proc; // set to processor, 
                              // which we got from the first lookup
                              // to get factory function.
};
```

So other threads, will just do

```
Message->proc->Handler(Message *);
```

This looks bad, but hope, is that this will help to separate message handler from the factory. This is for the case, when multiple type/subtype wants to create same Message, but handle it differently.

I was searching about this and came across :

http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/message-handling-without-dependencies/184429055?pgno=1

It provides a way to completely separate the message from the handler. But I was wondering if my simple scheme above will be considered an acceptable design or not. Also is this a wrong way of achieving what I want?

Efficiency, as in speed, is the most important requirement from this application. Already we are doing couple of memory Jumbs => 2 vectors + virtual function call the create the message. There are 2 deference to get to the handler, which is not good from caching point of view I guess.

Comment: no offence I think you haven't described your use cases clearly then jump to your design so quickly... at least you may need to address the expectation of performance on what kind of load? do you mind to write a brief on this?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by load. In our system, we have to process 200k messages per second. Without going into the actual product details. The server sends short configuration messages to the client. The configuration messages comes with a type,  subtype and data. There is a large no.  of type/subtype combination - say around 1000. These are consumed by a different no. of modules. So it's important to have a clean interface for all modules to register and receive the messages.

Comment: When do you expect the 'create' method to be called ? And what is the returned 'Message*' ? Would it be an empty message that you would be populating with the parsed data ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though your requirement is unclear, I think I have a design that might be what you are looking for.

Check out http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7f9d5e7d57e6261 for the fully fledged example.

It has following components:

1. An interface class for Message processors `IMessageProcessor`.
2. A base class representing a Message. `Message`
3. A registration class which is essentially a singleton for storing the message processors corresponding to (Type, Subtype) pair. `Registrator`. It stores the mapping in a `unordered_map`. You can also tweak it a bit for better performance. All the exposed API's of `Registrator` are protected by a `std::mutex`.
4. Concrete implementations of MessageProcessor. `AMsgProcessor` and `BMsgProcessor` in this case.
5. `simulate` function to show how it all fits together.

Pasting the code here as well:

```
/*
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230555/efficient-message-factory-and-handler-in-c
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>
#include <unordered_map>

class Message;

class IMessageProcessor
{
public:
  virtual Message* create() = 0;
  virtual void handle_message(Message*) = 0;
  virtual ~IMessageProcessor() {};
};

/*
 * Base message class
 */
class Message
{
public:
  virtual void populate() = 0;
  virtual ~Message() {};
};

using Type = int;
using SubType = int;
using TypeCombo = std::pair<Type, SubType>;
using IMsgProcUptr = std::unique_ptr<IMessageProcessor>;

/*
 * Registrator class maintains all the registrations in an
 * unordered_map.
 * This class owns the MessageProcessor instance inside the
 * unordered_map.
 */
class Registrator
{
public:
  static Registrator* instance();

  // Diable other types of construction
  Registrator(const Registrator&) = delete;
  void operator=(const Registrator&) = delete;

public:
  // TypeCombo assumed to be cheap to copy
  template <typename ProcT, typename... Args>
  std::pair<bool, IMsgProcUptr> register_proc(TypeCombo typ, Args&&... args)
  {
    auto proc = std::make_unique<ProcT>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    bool ok;
    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _(lock_);
      std::tie(std::ignore, ok) = registrations_.insert(std::make_pair(typ, std::move(proc)));
    }
    return (ok == true) ? std::make_pair(true, nullptr) : 
                          // Return the heap allocated instance back
                          // to the caller if the insert failed.
                          // The caller now owns the Processor
                          std::make_pair(false, std::move(proc));
  }

  // Get the processor corresponding to TypeCombo
  // IMessageProcessor passed is non-owning pointer
  // i.e the caller SHOULD not delete it or own it
  std::pair<bool, IMessageProcessor*> processor(TypeCombo typ)
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _(lock_);

    auto fitr = registrations_.find(typ);
    if (fitr == registrations_.end()) {
      return std::make_pair(false, nullptr);
    }
    return std::make_pair(true, fitr->second.get());
  }

  // TypeCombo assumed to be cheap to copy
  bool is_type_used(TypeCombo typ)
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _(lock_);
    return registrations_.find(typ) != registrations_.end();
  }

  bool deregister_proc(TypeCombo typ)
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _(lock_);
    return registrations_.erase(typ) == 1;
  }

private:
  Registrator() = default;

private:
  std::mutex lock_;
  /*
   * Should be replaced with a concurrent map if at all this
   * data structure is the main contention point (which I find
   * very unlikely).
   */
  struct HashTypeCombo
  {
  public:
    std::size_t operator()(const TypeCombo& typ) const noexcept
    {
      return std::hash<decltype(typ.first)>()(typ.first) ^ 
             std::hash<decltype(typ.second)>()(typ.second);
    }
  };

  std::unordered_map<TypeCombo, IMsgProcUptr, HashTypeCombo> registrations_;
};

Registrator* Registrator::instance()
{
  static Registrator inst;
  return &inst;
  /*
   * OR some other DCLP based instance creation
   * if lifetime or creation of static is an issue
   */
}


// Define some message processors

class AMsgProcessor final : public IMessageProcessor
{
public:
  class AMsg final : public Message 
  {
  public:
    void populate() override {
      std::cout << "Working on AMsg\n";
    }

    AMsg() = default;
    ~AMsg() = default;
  };

  Message* create() override
  {
    std::unique_ptr<AMsg> ptr(new AMsg);
    return ptr.release();
  }

  void handle_message(Message* msg) override
  {
    assert (msg);
    auto my_msg = static_cast<AMsg*>(msg);

    //.... process my_msg ?
    //.. probably being called in some other thread
    // Who owns the msg ??
    (void)my_msg; // only for suppressing warning

    delete my_msg;

    return;
  }

  ~AMsgProcessor();
};

AMsgProcessor::~AMsgProcessor()
{
}

class BMsgProcessor final : public IMessageProcessor
{
public:
  class BMsg final : public Message
  {
  public:
    void populate() override {
      std::cout << "Working on BMsg\n";
    }

    BMsg() = default;
    ~BMsg() = default;
  };

  Message* create() override
  {
    std::unique_ptr<BMsg> ptr(new BMsg);
    return ptr.release();
  }

  void handle_message(Message* msg) override
  {
    assert (msg);
    auto my_msg = static_cast<BMsg*>(msg);

    //.... process my_msg ?
    //.. probably being called in some other thread
    //Who owns the msg ??
    (void)my_msg; // only for suppressing warning

    delete my_msg;

    return;
  }

  ~BMsgProcessor();
};

BMsgProcessor::~BMsgProcessor()
{
}


TypeCombo read_from_network()
{
  return {1, 2};
}


struct ParsedData {
};

Message* populate_message(Message* msg, ParsedData& pdata)
{
  // Do something with the message
  // Calling a dummy populate method now
  msg->populate();
  (void)pdata;
  return msg;
}

void simulate()
{
  TypeCombo typ = read_from_network();
  bool ok;
  IMessageProcessor* proc = nullptr;

  std::tie(ok, proc) = Registrator::instance()->processor(typ);
  if (!ok) {
    std::cerr << "FATAL!!!" << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  ParsedData parsed_data;
  //..... populate parsed_data here ....

  proc->handle_message(populate_message(proc->create(), parsed_data));
  return;
}


int main() {

  /*
   * TODO: Not making use or checking the return types after calling register
   * its a must in production code!!
   */
  // Register AMsgProcessor
  Registrator::instance()->register_proc<AMsgProcessor>(std::make_pair(1, 1));
  Registrator::instance()->register_proc<BMsgProcessor>(std::make_pair(1, 2));

  simulate();

  return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

The major source of confusion here seems to be because the architecture of the even system is unknown.

Any self respecting event system architecture would look something like below:

1. A pool of threads polling on the socket descriptors.
2. A pool of threads for handling timer related events.
3. Comparatively small number (depends on application) of threads to do long blocking jobs.

So, in your case:

1. You will get network event on the thread doing `epoll_wait` or `select` or `poll`.
2. Read the packet completely and get the processor using `Registrator::get_processor` call.
   **NOTE**: `get_processor` call can be made without any locking if one can guarantee that the underlying `unordered_map` does not get modified i.e no new inserts would be made once we start receiving events.
3. Using the obtained processor we can get the `Message` and populate it.
4. Now, this is the part that I am not that sure of how you want it to be. At this point, we have the `processor` on which you can call `handle_message` either from the current thread i.e the thread which is doing `epoll_wait` or dispatch it to another thread by posting the job (Processor and Message) to that threads receiving queue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The reason I was having a pointer to the processor was that, and I mentioned this in the question, we need to cal the handler in a different thread. The message after receiving and parsing, is sent to other threads for processing. The processing is very time consuming, as it involves lot of PCI writes etc. We could have had a design of all the threads receive message and process it, but that would need some sort of locking. Hence we designed it as a pipeline. Do you think that is okay to keep pointer to proc in the message?

Comment: This creates sort of circular dependency, where processors should see the message and message inturn should see the processors. Probably resolved with forward declaration. In my original code, I had each module instantiate the processor. The base class of the processor, say IMessageProcessor, adds itself to the Registrator. register/unregister will be done by new/delete. This was so that I dont have to deal with the constructor arguments on the derived class. You solved it by using variadic template parameters.

Comment: Disadvantage with my scheme I think, is error in registration has to be handled as exceptions rather than return type. Do you have a comment on both the schemes?

Comment: @user361190 I have updated the answer since commenting it here was frustrating.

Comment: Thanks for the comments!

Comment: I think Arunmu's design can easily support sort of threading pool on epoll level.